# Which sections of the C standard prove the integer type correspondence?

Tags: c++, c, language-lawyer, c11

In one of the late drafts of C11 ([[C11_N1570]](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)) I fail to find a proof to the following statements (which, I believe, are commonly known), see below. Can anybody refer me to particular sections of the C standard that prove the sentences below? (or correct me if I'm wrong)

Type `short` is the same as `signed short` (TODO: link).
Type `[[un]signed] short` is the same as the corresponding `[[un]signed] short int` (TODO: link).

Type `int` is the same as `signed int` (TODO: link).

Type `long` is the same as `long int` (TODO: link).
Type `[[un]signed] long` is the same as the corresponding `[[un]signed] long int` (TODO: link).

Type `long long` is the same as `long long int` (TODO: link).
Type `[[un]signed] long long` is the same as the corresponding `[[un]signed] long long int` (TODO: link).

Ideally I would prefer this question answered both for C and C++, right now I'm interested in C.

Comment: While C and C++ share a lot of common features, they are two different languages. Which standard(s) are you *specifically* concerned with?

Comment: @tadman the first paragraph answers your question

Comment: And yet you start talking about C++ which the C standard, obviously, has *absolutely* no opinion about. Please don't conflate or confuse the two.

Comment: For C++ you can see [this table](https://eel.is/c++draft/tab:dcl.type.simple) in the draft standard

Comment: to answer the question, see 6.2.5/4  parenthesized sentence referring to 6.7.2/2

Comment: @tadman, I added a sentence in the end "... both for C and C++, right now I'm interested in C".

Comment: You should ask in relationship to specific standards. In this case do you mean C11 and C++...17? 20?

Comment: @tadman, my preference is to the latest versions of the published standards (C17, C++20), ideally such that I can double-check with the freely available late drafts.
But looks like M.M has answered my immediate question.

Comment: @RobinKuzmin I recommend removing the last sentence (the one that mentions C++) and removing the `c++` tag. As it stands, you appear to be asking two questions in one. Since the C and C++ standards are separate, independent documents, one should not try to cover both in a single SO question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Link to the online HTML version of the C standard: [section 6.7.2/2](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2p2). Possibly, together with [section 6.2.5/4](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.5p4).

Link to the online HTML version of the C++ standard: [[tab:dcl.type.simple]](https://eel.is/c++draft/tab:dcl.type.simple).

Comment: Answers should contain all the relevant information directly. External links are good for supplemental information but should be regarded as if they may change or vanish at any moment. And answers should explain, not just point to text.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Generally, I would agree with that. However, in this case, OP explicitly asked for references to standards, not for quotes or explanations.

Comment: On a first glance I thought you had linked to _the entire standard_, which would obviously be unhelpful.  What you actually seem to be saying is "C standard sections 6.7.2p2 and 6.2.5p4 guarantee these equivalences", and this does seem to be what OP wanted, but please don't make future readers dig that out of the URLs.

Comment: @zwol Good point. I reformatted the links to standard section names.